# Understand the vector space $ℝ^{[0,1]}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions, notation

I have trouble to understand the element of vector space $ℝ^{[0,1]}$. In the book it saying the elements are the real-value functions on $[0,1].$  May I have some examples of those function? and how to write all the set of functions?

Comment: $A^B$ means : The set of all functions from $B$ to $A$. In set notation ,for your case, $$\Bbb R^{[0,1]}:=\{f: [0,1] \to \Bbb R\}$$

For example, $f: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ is a member of $\Bbb R^{[0,1]}$

Comment: Thanks, your guys are really helpful!!!